# Узнать название кнопки

Tags: python, flask

Имею файл `index.html` следующего вида:

```
...
<body>
  <a href={{ url_for('on_create_model') }}><button>+RandomForest</button></a>
  <a href={{ url_for('on_create_model') }}><button>+GradientBoosting</button></a>
</body>
...
```

Как видно, при нажатии на кнопки вызывается функция `on_create_model`. Однако по моей задумке, поведение этой функции должно меняться в зависимости от текста под `button` (RandomForest или GradientBoosting). Могу ли я как-то передать текст кнопки в мою функцию, чтобы, например, банально напечатать этот текст в консоли.

```
@app.route('/model_creation')
def on_create_model():
    # model_name это как раз либо RandomForest либо GradientBoosting
    print(model_name) 
    return render_template(
        'something.html',
        model_name=model_name,
    )
```

Или возможен другой подход для решения моей задачи? Желательно не выходить за пределы Flask. (т.е. без использования javascript и тому подобное)

Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно передать название модели через url-параметр:

```py
...
<body>
  <a href={{ url_for('on_create_model', model_name='RandomForest') }}><button>+RandomForest</button></a>
  <a href={{ url_for('on_create_model', model_name='GradientBoosting') }}><button>+GradientBoosting</button></a>
</body>
...
```

При этом аннотация обработчика должна включать новый параметр:

```py
@app.route('/model_creation/<string:model_name>')
def on_create_model(model_name):
    print(model_name)
    ...
```